# How many AWS Athena recent query hits are kept?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Recent query searches are kept for 45 days according to the instructions in the official documentation. However, my query is not found because I use too many queries. Is there any additional limit on the number? For example, if only 1000 are stored.
[image]

- In addition to the 45-day limit, is there any guide in the official document about the number?
- It doesn't work in the console, is there a way to find out which queries I ran a week ago?